# Is OpenCV compatible with pyqt?

Tags: ros, opencv, pyqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello there,

I am using ROS to develop a system in my research. So, I am retrieving video images from the robot and I want to draw a circle on the screen to the object that the robot recognizes.
I have the code for the object recognition and the position of the object with respect to the video , I was thinking of using OpenCV, but I don't know if they are compatible with pyqt and python?

any help

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10052/is-opencv-compatible-with-pyqt?/) by [Shamma](https://answers.ros.org/users/376/shamma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can do it with opencv's [drawing functions](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_drawing_functions.html). Use [cvbridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) to create cv::Mat from sensor_msg::image without copying.

If you use pyqt anyway, why not use the drawing functions of qt? You can convert the images to QImage (e.g. as it is done [here (c++)](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rgbdslam/html/openni__listener_8cpp_source.html#l00319) from an opencv image) and use a QPainter, constructed with the image as parameter to use drawEllipse.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Shamma,

If your problem is just drawing circles, you could do it with opencv. Take a look at the face detection example, you will see how to draw circles.

Hope this helps,

Guido

---

Originally posted by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) with karma: 514 on 2011-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shamma](https://answers.ros.org/users/376/shamma/) on 2011-05-26**:
I had a look at it, I think I will utilize it ...